# Android ConstraintLayout animations excessively slow down the rendering: is it possible to avoid them?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm moving my first steps with ConstraintLayout in Android environment. I'm appreciating all its advantages but I've also some problems when, working at the the views in display mode, I've to wait an enormous amount of time till the arrows and all animations (that are thought to fulfill the hooking of each component) are completely loaded. Is there some way to use ConstraintLayout, with all its very useful functionalities, but avoiding arrows and similar animations which incredibly slow down the activity rendering and often lead the system to crash? I really hope you can help me. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Just to be clear, are you referring to animations in the GUI designer in *Android Studio*, or animations that you are applying to the contents of a `ConstraintLayout` in *your app*?

Answer (score 0):

Which animations are you talking about? I'm guessing the animations that we played when AutoConnect is ON? If so, you don't need to wait for them to finish -- you can continue to do things while they play -- once they complete they will do the connection. The animations only indicate that if you move the widgets, the connections will be removed.

Comment: Sorry Nicolas...I completely forgot to answer you few months ago and I've realized this only now, while checking other Stack Overflow messages. Thank you very much for your useful help. Better late than never :)!